# Toggle a single bit on Arduino + 74HC165 + SPI

Tags: arduino, bit-manipulation, spi, shift-register

Please, help me. I'm trying to connect the 74HC165 (8-bit input shift register) to Arduino UNO via SPI to check the state of 8 buttons. The response is going to be processe to change variable "controls", but it doesn't work properly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

/*  Latch contact */
enum { REG_LATCH = 8 };
int speed = 100;

/*  Variable to store the Controls state for further transfer */
static uint8_t controls = 0;

void setup()
{
  /*  Turn ON the UART  */
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /*  Turn On the SPI */
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(REG_LATCH, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  /*  Storing the previous system state   */
  static uint8_t previous_input = 00000000;

  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, LOW);
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH);

  /*  Read the inputs from shift register */  
  uint8_t input = SPI.transfer(0);

  /* If anything has ben changed - report to UART */

  if (input != previous_input)
    {  
      /*  Remebmer changed positions */
      uint8_t changed = input ^ previous_input;

      /*  Remember current state */
      previous_input = input;       

      Serial.println("Buttons State:\t\tControls State:");
      /* Run trough all inputs from shift register  */
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
          /* Print the state of currently checked input*/
          Serial.print(input & 1);
          /* If button is pressed and previously it was not, then  */
          if ((input & 1) & (changed & 1))
            {
              /* Highlight the current changes in system */
              Serial.print("_");                            
              /* Toggle controls in this position */
              controls = controls ^ (1 << i);
             }; /*Otherwise do nothing*/

          /*  Move to next bit of inputs. */
          input >>= 1;
          changed >>= 1;
        };

      Serial.print("\t\t");  
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
          /* Print current control  */
          Serial.print(controls);
          controls >>= 1;
        }
      Serial.println();       
  }
}
```

And what it writes to the Serial:

1) After pressing button 1:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
1_0000000       10000000
```

2) When it releases:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
00000000        00000000
```

3) After pressing button 7:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
0000001_0       64321684210
```

4) After its releasing:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
00000000        00000000
```

5) After pressing button 1:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
1_0000000       10000000
```

6) When it releases:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
00000000        00000000
```

How it supposed to work:

1) After pressing button 1:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
    1_0000000       10000000
```

2) After its release:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
    00000000        10000000
```

3) After pressing button 7:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
0000001_0       10000010
```

4) After its releasing

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
00000000        10000010
```

5) After next pressing of button 1:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
    1_0000000       00000010
```

6) After its releasing:

```
Buttons State:      Controls State:
    00000000        00000010
```

Help me, please.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First check your shift register is connected correctly. The best way of distinguishing hardware issues with software issues is to plug an oscilloscope on the output pin of your shift register.

Your REG_LATCH pin must be plugged to pin1 of your shift register (assuming we are talking about this one http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT165.pdf).

The way it works is that you must pull this pin down, transfer data then pull it up. Thus the sequence is rather:

```
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, LOW);
  /*  Read the inputs from shift register */  
  uint8_t input = SPI.transfer(0);
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH);
```

Then instead of shifting index and changed in your loop, I would have used this:

```
input & i
changed & i
```

or

```
input & (7 - i)
changed & (7 - i)
```

depending on the order your want to handle your bits.

Comment: The REG_LATCH is connected properly (as you've written - to pin 1). If change code to :

 digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, LOW);
  /*  Read the inputs from shift register */  
  uint8_t input = SPI.transfer(0); digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH); 

No interaction happens (no inputs read).
Using 

    input & i
    changed & i

Gives the same result, as was before.
What can be done else?

Comment: And I still can't understand, why it returns all "controls" to 0 after releasing of buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. 
I've made a mistake in depicturing of "Controls" state. Togling was working as it was supposed to work.

This is code for proper presenting:

```
#include <SPI.h>

/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */
/*  Global System variables                                                  */
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/*  Storing the previous system state */
static uint8_t previous_input = 0;
/*  Variable to store the Controls state for further transfer */
static uint8_t controls = 0;
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */
/*   Configuration of shift input register 74HC165  */
/*  Latch contact */
enum { REG_LATCH = 8 };
/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */

void setup()
{
  /*  Turn ON the UART  */
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /*  Turn On the SPI */
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(REG_LATCH, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH);
}

/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */

void print_bin_to_serial(int digit){
/* Run trough all inputs from shift register  */
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
          /* Print the state of currently checked input*/
          Serial.print(((digit << i) >> 7) & 1);
        };
}

/*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------  */

void loop()
{     
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, LOW);
  digitalWrite(REG_LATCH, HIGH);
  /*  Read the inputs from shift register */  
  uint8_t input = SPI.transfer(0);  

  /* If anything has ben changed - report to UART */
  if (input != previous_input)
    {  
      /*  Remember changed positions */
      uint8_t changed = input ^ previous_input;
      /*  Remember current state */
      previous_input = input;       
      /*  Fixing, what positions had to be switched  */
      uint8_t items_to_change = (input & changed);
      controls ^= items_to_change;
      /* Code is just for printing */      
      Serial.println("Buttons State:\t\tChanged:\t\tItems to change:\tControls State:");
      print_bin_to_serial(input);
      Serial.print("\t\t");  
      print_bin_to_serial(changed);   
      Serial.print("\t\t");  
      print_bin_to_serial(items_to_change);   
      Serial.print("\t\t");  
      print_bin_to_serial(controls);
      Serial.println();    
  };
}
```

@Tom, thanks for advise. That didn't fix a problem, but helped to make a code shorter.